# How to clear the list of options based on the other every time I switch between the options?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to update one list based on the selected option in another list but every time I change the item in the first list the options for that corresponding item gets appended in the second list and the list size increases. The following is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <select name = "country" id = "country" onchange = "myFunction()">
        <script>
            var country = new Array("India", "Thailand");
            var select = document.getElementById("country");
            for(var i = 0;i<country.length;i++)
            {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = option.value = country[i];
                select.add(option);
            }

            var cities = {
                "India":["Bangalore","Kolkata","Delhi", "Pune"],
                "Thailand":["Phuket", "Bangkok"]
            };
            function myFunction(){
                    if(selectCities!=null)selectCities=null;
                    var listCities=new Array();
                    var selectedCountry = document.getElementById("country").value;
                    listCities = cities[selectedCountry]
                    var selectCities = document.getElementById("city");
                    for(var i = 0;i<listCities.length;i++)
                    {
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.text = option.value = listCities[i];
                        selectCities.add(option);
                    }
            }
        </script>
    </select>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <select name = "city" id = "city">
    </select>
</body>
```

I am trying to display Bangalore, Kolkata, Delhi, Pune for India and Phuket, Bangkok for Thailand but each time I switch from India to Thailand and vice-versa the list of cities gets increased as the options are getting appended.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add one more function called `removeChildElements`.

Try code below :

```html
<select name = "country" id = "country" onchange = "myFunction()">
        <script>
            var country = new Array("India", "Thailand");
            var select = document.getElementById("country");
            for(var i = 0;i<country.length;i++)
            {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = option.value = country[i];
                select.add(option);
            }

            var cities = {
                "India":["Bangalore","Kolkata","Delhi", "Pune"],
                "Thailand":["Phuket", "Bangkok"]
            };
            function myFunction(){
                    if(selectCities!=null)selectCities=null;
                    var listCities=new Array();
                    var selectedCountry = document.getElementById("country").value;
                    listCities = cities[selectedCountry]
                    var selectCities = document.getElementById("city");
// this function would clear all child elements (options) from your selectCities
// You can use it on this way, too: removeChildElements('city'), function will recognize is it "passed" an object or just ID of element
                    removeChildElements(selectCities);
                    for(var i = 0;i<listCities.length;i++)
                    {
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.text = option.value = listCities[i];
                        selectCities.add(option);
                    }
            }
        </script>
    </select>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <select name = "city" id = "city">
    </select>
    
    <!-- this function will remove all child elements, in this case will clear your city selection, of parent one -->
    <script>
     function removeChildElements(el) {
      var ele;
      if (typeof el === 'object') { ele = el; } else { ele = document.getElementById(el); }
      if (ele != null) { while (ele.firstChild) { ele.removeChild(ele.firstChild); } }
}
    </script>
```

update: You can use that function for "clearing" some other `html` elements if You wouldn't use `innerHTML=""`

Answer (score 0):

May reset *selectCities* :

```
selectCities.innerHTML="";
```

Then append the new options.